# Can I set an app to ignore Do Not Disturb?

Tags: applications, ios, do-not-disturb, alert

I have an app that informs me of critical events - for example, scheduled automated tasks failing.

But when I set my phone to Do Not Disturb, this app goes silent as well.

Is there a way I can set this particular app to play sounds even if my phone is on Do Not Disturb?

Comment: The answer in the redirected link is outdated, but I've corrected that here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/447998/160704