# Do not disturb mode - but allow certain apps

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to turn on do not disturb mode on my iPhone. But we use a pager application for work, and I want that application to still be able to notify me and make noises.

How do I do that? I can only figure out how to allow contacts to not be in do not disturb mode.

Comment: +1 - this would be a very useful whitelist for some people

Comment: Please send Apple feedback about this. More feedback means a higher probability to get this feature in the future releases of iOS. Feedback URL: https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you cannot (on a non-jailbroken device).  There is currently no iPhone feature available to exempt a specific application from either Silent or Do Not Disturb mode.

Comment: This answer is fortunately outdated! See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/447998/160704

Answer (score 3):

Similarly to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/234873/160704) about syncing Do Not Disturb mode across devices, this answer appears outdated as well.

You can now, with Apple's Focus Feature, allow certain applications or certain users to create and trigger notifications that will display and sound for you in your chosen focus. This has to obviously be configured in settings but is absolutely possible.

Here is the official Apple Information as of September, 2022. It will naturally go out of date in a few years when all these tech companies feel like slapping another new coat of paint on top of all of their old work.

> Set up your Focus. You can select allowed or silenced notifications from people and apps, connect your Lock Screen or Home Screen, have this Focus turn on automatically, and add Focus filters. [0](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212608)

Answer (score 1):

If the device is jailbroken, you can use [Banner Sounds](http://www.tateu.net/repo/html/?p=bannersounds) to allow certain notifications which match filters you configure the ability to bypass Do Not Disturb.

Comment: This answer is fortunately outdated! See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/447998/160704

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 13, the only way you can do this without jail breaking is to set up your pager application to send SMS or make phone calls, then you can set up a contact to bypass silent mode and Do Not Disturb.

Comment: This answer is fortunately outdated! See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/447998/160704